# Setting a delegate from FPPopover without a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsnotificationcenter

I'm working on an iPhone app which uses a FPPopover, an open source library that enables popovers on iPhones. I have my `PopoverTVC` displaying what I want, but I'm unable to figure out how to set my `SavedPOITableViewController` as a delegate of `PopoverTVC` without a segue.

[FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover/)

`SavedPOITableViewController` opens `PopoverTVC` from a `UIBarButtonItem`

Should I even be using a delegate, or should I set up a `NSNotification` on my SavedPOITVC's `viewDidLoad` to listen for changes and post a notification on my `PopoverTVC` when the `myVariable` has updated?

Here's how my popover is instantiated on my `SavedPOITableViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)filterButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    // The view controller you want to present as a popover
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = sender;
    UIView *buttonView = [buttonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
    PopoverTableViewController *categoryList = [[PopoverTableViewController alloc]init];
    FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc]initWithViewController:categoryList];
categoryList.delegate = self; // this doesn't work

    [popover setArrowDirection:FPPopoverArrowDirectionUp];
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:buttonView];    
}
```

I know this sounds startlingly stupid, but it's stumped me for more time than I care to admit.

When I try to set the delegate, I get this error:

```
    Assigning to 'id<PopoverTableViewControllerDelegate>' from 
incompatible type 'SavedPOITableViewController *const __strong'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `PopoverTVC` did not have a storyboard. I didn't bother to put one in because it's "out there on it's own". I threw an orphaned TableViewController on interface builder, assigned its class as `PopoverTVC` and I'm the delegate works, despite a warning.

I don't understand why it works with the addition of an orphaned storyboard, but it didn't before with just code. If anyone can explain that, I'd love to hear the explanation.